# Add placeholder or default value to captcha text field

Tags: 7, forms, webforms, captcha

There is a webform in my website, I added the captcha to this webform using this code:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if (strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form')) {
        $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
                '#type' => 'captcha',
                '#captcha_type' => 'image_captcha/Image',
        );
    }
}
```

This works fine. I need to insert a placeholder or default the text field of the image. I mean in the following picture :

[image]

the `What code is in the image?` should move inside the text field. How do I can do this?

Even though it is possible to make this done using javscript but I need to make this done using form alter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this module too:

https://www.drupal.org/project/form_placeholder

it worked for me very nice

Comment: kheili sepasgozaram

Comment: khahesh mikonam!! :)))

Answer (score 1):

Use an `#after_build` form element to drop the placeholder attribute into the form:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if (strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form')) {
        $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
                '#type' => 'captcha',
                '#captcha_type' => 'image_captcha/Image',
        );
        $form['#after_build'][] = 'THEME_captcha_alter';
    }
}
function THEME_captcha_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['my_captcha_element']['captcha_widgets']['captcha_response']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => 'My Placeholder');
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: `theme_captcha_alter` doesn't exists at all!

Comment: I guess could have made that clearer. `THEME_captcha_alter` can be any arbitrary function name. The important thing is it can alter the captcha element after the captcha module is finished building it .

Comment: Ah, I forgot to include `$form['#after_build'][] = 'THEME_captcha_alter';` statement